# How to set the width of my text back to 0 so that I can crapit?

Tags: c++, text, sfml, word-wrap

For some reason, after the first line, my text continuously add new line whenever a press a key. I'm not sure how to fix it, I've tried various ways but it still didn't work.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    sf::Vector2i screenDimensions(800, 600);
    sf::Vector2i blockDimensions(10, 10);

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode( screenDimensions.x, screenDimensions.y), "SFML Tutorial", sf::Style::Close | sf::Style::Titlebar);

    //window.setKeyRepeatEnabled(false);

    sf::Font font;
    if (!font.loadFromFile("OCRAStd.otf"))
    {
        cout << "Can't find the font file" << endl;
    }

    sf::String sentence;
    sf::Text text(sentence, font, 40);
    //for font style such as Bold, Underline, and Italicized
    text.setStyle(sf::Text::Bold | sf::Text::Underlined);
    text.setFillColor(sf::Color(44, 127, 255));
    text.setOutlineColor(sf::Color(44, 127, 255));

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
                case(sf::Event::Closed):
                    window.close();
                    break; 
                case(sf::Event::KeyPressed) :
                    if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape)
                        window.close();
                    break;
                case sf::Event::TextEntered:
                    int width = text.getGlobalBounds().width;

                    if (width >= screenDimensions.x)
                    {
                        sentence.insert(sentence.getSize(), "\n");
                        width = 0;

                    }

                    if (event.text.unicode >= 32 && event.text.unicode <= 126)
                        sentence += (char)event.text.unicode;
                    else if (event.text.unicode == 8 && sentence.getSize() > 0)
                        sentence.erase(sentence.getSize() - 1, sentence.getSize());

                    text.setString(sentence);

                    break;
            }
        }

        window.draw(text);
        window.display();
        window.clear();

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because once your text reaches the side of the window, its already wide enough to trigger the if statement that adds newlines each time you press key.

```
case sf::Event::TextEntered:
    if (event.text.unicode >= 32 && event.text.unicode <= 126)
        sentence += (char)event.text.unicode;
    else if (event.text.unicode == 8 && sentence.getSize() > 0)
        sentence.erase(sentence.getSize() - 1, sentence.getSize());

    text.setString(sentence);

    if (text.getGlobalBounds().width > screenDimensions.x)
    {
        sentence.insert(sentence.getSize() - 1, "\n");
        text.setString(sentence);
    }
    break;
```

This piece of code inserts new character into your text, **and then** checks if bounds are exceeded. If so, it inserts a newline before freshly added character.